# Can I use Amazon Rekognition without an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I want to use the Firebase with the Amazon Rekognition is it possible to use?

I read Class for Rekognition for Node.js it has the S3 command in the code.

Comment: What Rekognition functionality do you wish to use? It has some features that use S3 and some that don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

No , you don't need to use **s3** if you don't want. Using s3 provides **low latency** but you can use **Rekognition** services directly via API calls , the response of the API calls will contain your desired results in **json** format which you can use as you want.

Further if you use direct API calls , then you have to pass your images in **base-64 encoded** format while using REkognition API's.

Also you can use AWS SDK's for different programming languages which will make your task easier to use different AWS services easily.

e.g for detecting labels in python :

```
import boto3
from PIL import Image
import io
local='images/4.jpeg'
client = boto3.client('rekognition')
image = Image.open(local)

stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()

response = client.detect_labels(
    Image={'Bytes':image_binary}
    )


print(response)
```

while some rekognition services will require s3 to work.