# How to test Rekognition from AWS locally without using S3 in detecting texts from images

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to scan for texts from images but I couldn't find source codes without using an S3 bucket. This is the only source code I found but it uses an S3. I'm using python for this project.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detecting-text-procedure.html

```
import boto3

if __name__ == "__main__":

bucket='bucket'
photo='text.png'

client=boto3.client('rekognition')


response=client.detect_text(Image={'S3Object':{'Bucket':bucket,'Name':photo}})

textDetections=response['TextDetections']
print ('Detected text')
for text in textDetections:
        print ('Detected text:' + text['DetectedText'])
        print ('Confidence: ' + "{:.2f}".format(text['Confidence']) + "%")
        print ('Id: {}'.format(text['Id']))
        if 'ParentId' in text:
            print ('Parent Id: {}'.format(text['ParentId']))
        print ('Type:' + text['Type'])
        print
```

Found one here [Can I use Amazon Rekognition without an S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034435/can-i-use-amazon-rekognition-without-an-s3-bucket) and ran it's different from what I need because it detects labels only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Amazon Rekognition without an S3 bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034435/can-i-use-amazon-rekognition-without-an-s3-bucket)

Comment: @vahdet that was for detecting labels. It's different from detecting texts from images I think.

Comment: `detect_text` can also have the parameter as `(Image={'Bytes':image_binary})` just like in the case of `detect_labels`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DetectText` method in Rekognition API (for boto, `detect_text`) can take one of the following parameters:

- a reference to an image in an Amazon S3 bucket
- base64-encoded image bytes

So, if you are not to use S3 bucket, you have to provide its **bytes**. There is no third way is mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectText.html). The input structure is depicted as follows:

```
{
  "Image": { 
    "Bytes": blob,
    "S3Object": { 
      "Bucket": "string",
       "Name": "string",
       "Version": "string"
     }
  }
}
```

And, to acquire the byte stream of a non-S3 image; you can copy the implementation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51035516/4636715):

```
client = boto3.client('rekognition')

image_path='images/4.jpeg'
image = Image.open(image_path)

stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()

response = client.detect_text(Image={'Bytes':image_binary})
```

Comment: Great! I will test this locally when I get back thanks.

Comment: In the docs it says "In the DetectText operation, you supply an input image either as a **base64-encoded** byte array or as an image stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.". The part about "base64-encoded" doesn't seem to be correct.